# How to set PayPal recurring payments with different billing cycles & amounts using PayPal rest-api-sdk?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried the following code to set different billing cycles but it's not working. What is the error of this code?

Thanks in advance!

```php
$paymentDefinition_0 = new PaymentDefinition();
$paymentDefinition_1 = new PaymentDefinition();

$paymentDefinition_0->setName('1stPayment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => $request->20,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
$paymentDefinition_1->setName('2nd Payment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => $request->30,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
$plan->setPaymentDefinitions(array(
    $paymentDefinition,
    $paymentDefinition_1
));
```

Comment: 20 and 30 are technically constants, you can't have them as names in form requests or access them as properties of objects, that's a syntax error

Comment: So how can i fix this?

Comment: I posted an answer

Comment: Oh sorry it's correct. If any other prob?

Comment: other prob = other question

Answer (score 2):

20 and 30 are technically constants, you can't have them as names in form requests or access them as properties of objects, that's a syntax error

Either hardcode the values if they're constant

```php
$paymentDefinition_0->setName('1stPayment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => 20,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
$paymentDefinition_1->setName('2nd Payment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => 30,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
```

Or give them a string name in the HTML form and access that name as a property of the request object

For example

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="number" name="paymentDefinition_0" value="20"><br>
    <input type="number" name="paymentDefinition_1" value="30"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And access accordingly

```php
$paymentDefinition_0->setName('1stPayment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => $request->paymentDefinition_0,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
$paymentDefinition_1->setName('2nd Payment')
    ->setType('REGULAR')
    ->setFrequency('DAY')
    ->setFrequencyInterval('1')
    ->setCycles('1000')
    ->setAmount(new Currency(array(
        'value' => $request->paymentDefinition_1,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    )));
```

Hope this helps